# Question regarding using both Firebase and REST APIs in application

Tags: firebase, rest, api, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have been creating a flutter app and am using firebase for authentication.
Is it possible and best practice to use the firebase only for the authentication and use REST APIs via http package for the CRUD operations instead of using cloud firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it sure is possible, and common.  If you want to send the user credentials to your backend for verification, you should use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [verify a user ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).